# How do I remove Word markup crap when inserting to a form?

Tags: php, ms-word, tinymce, textarea, fckeditor

I'm building a CMS in PHP and one dread I have is that the users will have to fill the data in from existing Word (and Excel, but nevermind that) documents. Now, I've seen what happens when they carelessly copy and paste from Word to a textarea: the database got filled with crap markup.

Now, I could certainly strip all markup myself, but I'd have to start learning about it first. So I ask you: have you tested some functionality - plugins of the usual suspects (tinyMCE, FCKeditor, etc) that helps here? Bonus for the least intrusive solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly most of the HTML editor controls I've used either:

1. Have a button to strip out various elements of mark up (word, html, script, etc)
2. Strip out **all** markup on paste via JavaScript.

If you leave it to a button, then generally the non-technical users will forget to press it because they don't (some would say "shouldn't have to") care about it :(

With a bit of playing around with Regular Expressions (now you have another problem ;)) you could do something similar to 2 but just for word xml.

Answer (score 3):

I have found FCKEditor to handle text yanked and thrown at it from Word documents, much better than tinyMCE.

Comment: The existing website I was talking about in the question already uses FCK, although not the latest version. Is it a recent improvement?

Comment: @Moranar: I can't say. I am using version 2.6.3. It is just that when using tinyMCE, I found that it made it difficult to properly edit text copied from a Word document. FCKEditor, in contrast, did not have any of those issues.

Comment: The paste from Word feature has been in for awhile. Not sure how long. It also auto-picks up the need to do Word pasting when a user uses the browser Edit->Paste or Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found [a plugin for TinyMCE](http://www.vivvo.net/forums/showthread.php?t=2043) that apparently does what I wanted. Still, this asks for the users to press a button to paste, which is a bit less than ideal. Anything better?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET? [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)'s [RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) has worked very well for me