# PHP mailer, preserve line breaks from MS Word

Tags: php, email, ms-word

I have a web form where users submit resume info. Invariably, they copypaste from MS Word. I've got all the screwy characters fixed so that my client can see all the curly quotes and bullets and what-not, but I can't figure out how to preserve line-breaks.

tldr: is there a way to preserve line-breaks pasted from Word in a PHP mailer form?

(I've already suggested that we just allow .doc uploads of resumes but the client didn't go for it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and the [paste](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste) plugin; enable `pasteword` option.

You can send text as an HTML message.

Otherwise look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875027/clean-microsoft-word-pasted-text-using-javascript).