# String replace with regex for copied text

Tags: javascript, jquery

While copying text from word file to text editor I am getting html code like,

```
<p><br></p>
<p> <br></p>
<p>  <br></p>
<p>    <br></p>
```

I want to replace above code with empty text like this,

```
var updated = copyieddata.replace('<p><br></p>', '');
updated = updated.replace('<p> <br></p>', '');
updated = updated.replace('<p>  <br></p>', '');
updated = updated.replace('<p>   <br></p>', '');
```

How to implement above functionality by using Regex to avoid repetition.

Comment: what the actual output you want?

Comment: Copy without format :)

Comment: I need basic format.

Comment: I want remove following code because these  are creating extra lines.

 "<p><br></p>
<p> <br></p>
<p>  <br></p>
<p>    <br></p>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pedram's answer is probably the easiest way to achieve what you want.

However, if you want to only remove the `<p> <br></p>` tags and **keep all other tags** intact, then you need a regular expression that gets all parts of your string that:

- Start with `<p>` and end with `</p>`
- Have only `<br>` or *whitespace* in between

The regular expression you need would look like this: `/<p>(\s|<br>)*<\/p>/g`

This expression looks for any substring that starts with `<p>`, has *zero or more* occurrences of either whitespace (`\s`) or the `<br>` tag, and ends with `</p>`.

The `/g` at the end ensures that if there are multiple occurrences of the pattern in the string, then every pattern is matched. Omitting `/g` would match only the first occurence of the pattern in your string.

So, your code would look something like this:

```
var pattern = /<p>(\s|<br>)*<\/p>/g;
var updated = copyieddata.replace(pattern, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is convert `html` to `text` (it remove all additional `html` tags, and you get clean text) but also you use this topics to learn how format `ms word` texts.

[Jquery Remove MS word format from text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417479/jquery-remove-ms-word-format-from-text-area)

[Clean Microsoft Word Pasted Text using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875027/clean-microsoft-word-pasted-text-using-javascript)

```js
var text = $('#stack');
text.html(text.text());
console.log(text.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stack">
some text
<p><br></p>
<p> <br></p>
<p>  <br></p>
<p>    <br></p>
some text
</div>
```

Or you use this to replace all `<br>` and `<p>` tags.

```js
$("#stack").html(
  $("#stack").html()
  .replace(/\<br\>/g, "\n")
  .replace(/\<br \/\>/g, "\n")
  .replace(/\<p>/g, "\n")
  .replace(/\<\/p>/g, "\n")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stack">
some text
<p><br></p>
<p> <br></p>
<p>  <br></p>
<p>    <br></p>
some text
</div>
```

Instead of `"\n"` you can use nothing like this `""`